# How to fix 'character map file `UTF-8' not found'

Tags: utf-8, locale, redhat-containers

I'm setting up a  UBI rhel8 container. I need to execute this command:

```sh
localedef -f UTF-8 -i en_US en_US.UTF-8
```

which failed with:

```
character map file `UTF-8' not found: No such file or directory
cannot read character map directory `/usr/share/i18n/charmaps': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You need to install these packages

```
yum -y install glibc-locale-source glibc-langpack-en
```

and then re-run localedef command

Comment: Had to reboot like two times.

Comment: Be aware, that `gzip` was removed from UBI Images that might fail `localedef` (see https://access.redhat.com/solutions/6540691 for details)

Comment: I also needed to install gzip in order to run localedef

Answer (score 10):

On Debian/Ubuntu, I was able to solve this via `apt install locales`.

Comment: But this is about ubi8 images which are redhat specific.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same symptom (locale-gen can't find charmap files) after upgrading from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 in WSL 1. The problem is that there is a bug in WSL 1 that prevents gunzip from running. This is a problem for locale-gen because, at least in Ubuntu 22.04, the charmap files in /usr/share/i18n/charmaps are stored in GZip *.gz format. Apparently, locale-gen depends on gunzip to unzip the charmap files, and when it can't run it, it is stuck.

**The solution was**

1. copy UTF-8.gz to the Windows filesystem
2. unzip it to UTF-8 with a Windows tool (such as 7-zip)
3. copy UTF-8 back to /usr/share/i18n/charmaps

Then locale-gen worked correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I encountered same issue when run `localedef -i zh_CN -f UTF-8 zh_CN.UTF-8` in docker container (`opensuse/leap:latest`). And then I installed gzip in the container after see your tip, then `localedef` successfully generated locale file.